# Config entity vs custom tables

Tags: 8, entities

I am working on a custom shop module.

i have a custom entity content for my products and i want add some configuration for shipment.

For example :

my product has a weight and differents price for a weight.

So i have 3 way i think :

- Custom table, but i am looking for a better way
- Config Entity ?
- Entity content ?

i use drupal console, but when i create a ConfigEntity type, i can't add custom field like weight / price.
I can juste create a line with a machine name, i don't know how work this entity.

I need to add line like this :

**First item** 
Weight min : 100
Weight max : 500
Price : 10$

**Second item** 
Weight min : 500
Weight max : 1000
Price : 20$

.......

What i should use for add config like this ?

Custom tables ? Config Entity ? Entity content ?

Comment: I am unclear what the actual question is. Is it "How do I add fields to a config entity?" or "Should I use a config entity or a custom table?"

Comment: i know we can't add custom field to configEntity, the question is what i need to use for get config to my module

Comment: It is possible to add fields to configuration entities.

Comment: oh, i read it wasn't... ok so i ll look into this thank you

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. You should be able to add an arbitrary field in your configuration schema YAML. I think the [key module schema](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/key/tree/config/schema/key.schema.yml?h=8.x-1.x) does this. Also https://www.drupal.org/node/1905070